# Build.gradle file error while connecting to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to connect my app with firebase But I dont know why its givung me this error.

> Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

I tried to sought out the error but still its not working.Also I have added the image below ,And also adding the build.gradles files.

this is my build.gradle(Module.app)file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.moviebookingapp2"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    compile'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.3.1'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'


}
```

this is my build.gradle file for(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]/i.stack.imgur.com/Uqlza.png

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

Comment: Yes, but it is telling you that you have to fix the build issues, check the logcat the issue should be there so you can know what the problem is

Comment: No,ACtually in the logcat section there is no error displaying